# Access global data structure

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and trying to make a map that all the source files will be able to access. Here is a simplified version of the problematic code. Every header file has a header guard, I just didn't type them here.

```
// main.cpp

#include "client.hpp"
int main(void){
    init();
    search();
}


// util.cpp

#include "util.hpp"
std::map<int, STUDENT_TYPE> dataBase;
init(){
    dataBase[0] = STUDENT_TYPE(14, 4.0);
    // more students....
}


// util.hpp

#include <map>

struct STUDENT_TYPE{
    int age;
    int grade;
    STUDENT_TYPE(int age, int grade) : age(age), grade(grade){}

};
extern std::map<int, STUDENT_TYPE> dataBase;



// client.cpp
#include "client.hpp"
void search(){
    std::cout << dataBase[0].grade << std::endl;

}



// client.hpp
#include "util.hpp"
void search();
```

The problem is that the compiler failed to build at the search function. It gives a big chain of errors. The last error or the cause of all the error is that the constructor of STUDENT_TYPE require 2 fields while given 0. I suspect that client can't access the STUDENT_TYPE struct inside the dataBase. I don't how to fix it or exactly how it happened. I just want a big table of students that all the files in the program can access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler is telling you exactly what's wrong.  Your student type doesn't have a default constructor and it's being used.

Why is it being used?

Because `map::operator []` will create a default constructed instance to return if an entry doesn't yet exist for that key.  Even if this never happens, the compiler still has to compile that branch and it can't here.

Two ways to fix:

1. Give your student type a meaningful default.
2. Don't use `map::operator[]`.  Instead use `map::find`.

Comment: Thank you very much sir. The first solution worked! I'm not really familiar with map::find, need some more research. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

First solution; don't have a global data structure. There is normally no need at at all to have such a thing.

Secondly, understand what header guards do - they prevent the body of a header file being included in the *same* translation unit. They have no effect if the header file is included in multiple .cpp files.

Thirdly, when you post questions about problems here, post the full text of the error messages you are getting.

Comment: Those might be good tips, but I don't think they are relevant to his error.

Comment: @Mikel Possibly or possibly not - he hasn't posted the real code, so I did make some assumptions. He does say he has a global variable.

Comment: Any suggestion on the alternative of a global data structure? I'm new, I just don't know how to properly handle that.

Comment: @Tony As a first approximation of a solution, declare it as a variable in main(), and pass it to other functions as a parameter.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will use it sometimes.